# Retrieving a JSON file in JavaScript from AWS S3 and Displaying it in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 which I have uploaded a JSON file to a bucket. When I run this code, nothing is returned. I am unsure what is wrong. Any advice would be helpful.

```
//Javascript to get JSON file

var jsondata = $.getJSON("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BucketName/MYData.json");
var data = JSON.parse(jsondata);
var temp = data.test;
$('#dataJSON').html(temp);

--------------------------
//HTML to Display

<div id= "dataJSON"></div>
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is probably an asynchronous function. It'll never return the data.